# Django forms widgets Textarea is directly set to type hidden but need it visible

Tags: html, django, forms, model

My problem is i set a form from a model to change the value of the field "description" of this model :

Model :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_img = models.ForeignKey(Image,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='images',null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Form :

```
class ChangeUserDescription(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['description']
        widgets = {
            'description': forms.Textarea()
        }
        labels = {
            'description':'Description'
        }
```

template :

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

But in result of this code I obtain this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="brsd4oO0qhMw2K8PyCIgSgEMqy7QFvEjTHaR6wTJmyWffJaCX5XyOMDLrGldZ3ji">
<button type="submit">Save changes</button>
```

The issue is that i get : type="hidden" in the input whereas i want it to be visible and i do not specified in the widgets that it must be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hidden input field that you are referring to is the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="brsd4oO0qhMw2K8PyCIgSgEMqy7QFvEjTHaR6wTJmyWffJaCX5XyOMDLrGldZ3ji">
```

This is Django's [CSRF token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/), which you have correctly included in your form, and should always be an `<input type="hidden"`.

You have not shown us your template code, but as long as you correctly pass the `form` variable to your template, the following code should work:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  Please enter your description here: {{ form.description }}

  <button>Submit</button>

  {% if not form %}
    You have forgot to add the <tt>form</tt> variable to your template!
  {% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: I added the template, i tried your code but nothing change the input is still hidden and i juste see the sentences : Please enter your description here: before the submit button

Comment: Have you passed the `form` variable to your template?

Comment: Ok in fact you right i'm sorry my issue was really simple. Thanks a lot